# Get all items and sort the items used in a relationship on top in Symfony

Tags: symfony, relationship

Okay, so when editing a slideshow, the user needs to see a list of **all** slides (both slides that are used in the slideshow and those who aren't). The slides that are used in the slideshow needs to be sorted based on the intersection entity, all the other slides needs to be sorted below those slides based on ID.

I have 3 entities:

Slideshow:

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowSlideshowSlide", mappedBy="slideshow", fetch="EAGER", indexBy="sort")
  */
  private $slides;
```

SlideshowSlideshowSlide:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Slideshow", inversedBy="slides", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="slideshow_id", nullable=false)
 */
private $slideshow;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowSlide", inversedBy="slideshows", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $slideshowSlide;
```

SlideshowSlide:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowSlideshowSlide", mappedBy="slideshow", fetch="EAGER", indexBy="sort")
 */
private $slides;
```

I tried adding a new function in my repository (`SlideshowSlideRepository`):

```
public function findAndSort(Slideshow $slideshow)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.slideshows', 'slideshowlink')
        ->join('slideshowlink.slideshow', 'slideshowlinkslideshow')
        ->where('slideshowlinkslideshow.id = :slideshowid')
        ->setParameter('slideshowid', $slideshow->getId())
        ->orderBy('slideshowlink.sort')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

And use this as my render:

```
return $this->render('slideshows/edit.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'slides' => $slideshowSlideRepository->findAndSort($slideshow),
    'slideshow' => $slideshow
]);
```

But when I dump `slides`, it only has the slide used in the slideshow, but not the slide that isn't and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First off, use something like 'slideshowLinkSlideshow' instead of 'slideshowlinkslideshow'.  What you have now can make your eyes bleed trying to read it.  And if your are starting from SlideshowSlideRepository that I would have expected joining on .slides.  It's all quite confusing. The where condition will filter out everything not in a particular slide how so it is not surprising you are not getting the unused slides. In the end, once you do get all your slides, I expect you will need a custom php sort.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the repository method?
In your Slideshow entity, you should have a function: getSlides()

Add **OrderBy** annotation to your **OneToMany** relation:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowSlideshowSlide", mappedBy="slideshow", fetch="EAGER", indexBy="sort")
* @ORM\OrderBy({"sort" = "DESC"})
*/
private $slides;
```

And get all slides for this slideshow:

```
return $this->render('slideshows/edit.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'slides' => $slideshowSlideRepository->getSlides(),
    'slideshow' => $slideshow
]);
```

Comment: Seems to work fine, thanks (just saying you made a small mistake with `getSlides()` that should be `findAll()`

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake, but not here...
Instead of $slideshowSlideRepository->getSlides() it should be $slideshow->getSlides()
It's a very powerful side of Doctrine in Symfony (Eloquent in Laravel), you can get related items from both sides.
In your case, you should have:

.....
`private $slides`;
....
    `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->slides= new ArrayCollection();
    }`
...
    `public function getSlides(): Collection
    {
        return $this->slides;
    }`

Comment: Using `$slideshow->getSlides()` will indeed get all slides in the current slideshow but not the other slides.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because you filter the slides in your repository function `->where('slideshowlinkslideshow.id = :slideshowid')`
So you'll get the slides only for the current slideshow

Comment: That's a mistake on my part then which I didn't see (I was thinking because the relationship needs to be done on a certain slideshow but because I used left join it should get all slides)

Comment: Also I didn't test it well it doesn't work anyways.

Comment: So am I right that you want to show all slides: but slideshow slides on top, then all other slides?

Comment: Yes exactly. Slides within the slideshow (slideshow slides) on top, sorted by the sort property from the intersection entity (sort column in the intersection table in the database) and below that all other slides sorted on their id.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**

**In your Controller:**

```
$slideShowSlides = $slideshow->getSlides() // the current slideshow slides, will be sorted by sort coulmn DESC (doctrine annotation)
$otherSlides = $slideshowSlideRepository->getOtherSlides($slideshow);
$slides = new ArrayCollection(
    array_merge($slideShowSlides , $otherSlides)
);
```

**In your SlideshowSlideRepository:**

```
public function getOtherSlides(Slideshow $slideshow)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->where('s.slideshow != :slideshowId')
        ->setParameter('slideshowId', $slideshow->getId())
        ->orderBy('s.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**Option #2 (php sort)**

```
$slides = $slideshowSlideRepository->findAll();
// sorting
uasort($all,  function ($a, $b) use($slideshow) {
    if($a->getSlideshow() !== null &&  $a->getSlideshow()->getId() == $slideshow->getId()){
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});
```

in **uasort**, you can make additional sorting by ID/sort and etc